# What is the point of the 'model' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[model](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model) has no tag wiki and seems like a pretty useless tag to me. Any thoughts? Does it have a scope or should it be deleted?

Comment: I tried to kill it silently but failed, it has to be done by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[model](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model) is not a role [model](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model) of tags. Not a good tag to preserve.**

If my hunch is correct, model is supposed to be for questions about $\ldots$ models. But since almost everything in chemistry is explained by some sort of model we have to tag every question with **[model](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model)**.

BTW I'm kidding. The applicability of the tag to everything means it's either a "meta" tag or needs to be closed as "too broad". It seems no one thought this could be a tag so we didn't get enough tagging to notice it, but it seems it was a tag introduced in the early days of beta when stuff weren't that $\ldots$ consistent.

15 questions are a harmless retag, but if we're feeling lazy, I can add it to the TRE checklist.

Comment: Oh BTW the syntax `**[tag:foo]**` looks cool.